# How to dig an elliptical hole in blender (iphone)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

I am a beginner,
My view builds a phone model, I don't know how to make the speaker part

[image]

Comment: you have a lot of tutorials on how to make holes in objects, don't use boolean though: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+how+to+make+holes+in+objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: My topology was quite ugly so I reworked a simpler one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, good day. It is very easy to make any kind of holes in blender and can be done in many different ways like. But the easiest way of doing it is by either doing Shift+Ctrl+B (Done on vertices) or Ctrl+B (Done on edges). These "expands" the edge/vertices in a way. Ill leave you to do the rest, I hope this helped and experiment with these too!