# Material keeps apply to more than one face but not others?

Tags: faces, geometry

I was able to add material to the camera and speaker holes but when I try to add that same black material to the screen that will surrounded by the white it applies it to the whole front side? Not sure why this happening because it is a separate face when I select it? I'm very new to Blender and trying to figure all this out on my own.

Bonus question: Can someone please please please guide me on how to fix the little cracks/lines that show up on the home button and near the front camera when in render mode?
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52216

Comment: if I select the screen and assign a material it seems to work fine. About your cracks, your topology is not very good, you should follow a tutorial about how to model this kind of object

Comment: Are you selecting the center face? Not the entire front side of the phone? Also that last part wasn't very helpful at all. Obviously my topology is messed up and thats why I asked for help. Please only respond with helpful solutions.

Comment: I've reworked a topology for a iphone here, maybe it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112612/how-to-dig-an-elliptical-hole-in-blender