# How do i triangulate Ngons properly?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow, geometry

i´ve this mesh that is triangulated with the triangulate modifier, but it looks really ugly.
What should i do in this case?
Should i add more verts to avoid small angles?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to work with quads, maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112612/how-to-dig-an-elliptical-hole-in-blender-iphone

Comment: Hello :). Moonboots is right, quads are easier to work with. However if you're not using Subdivision, you can also use n-gons on flat areas without a lot of issues.